# How to prove that problem is NP-hard by making a reduction?

Tags: graph-theory, approximation, approximation-theory, np-complete

Convering by triples

Data: A set Y of cardinality 3n and a family C = ($C_{1},...C_{m}$) of triples of elements of Y: for all i, $C_{i}$ $\subset Y$ and |$C_{i}$| = 3.

We admit that COVERING BY TRIPLES is NP-complete.

Problem: Is there a subset $C^{'}$ of C which forms a partition of Y: i.e. such that the element of $C^{'}$ are pairwise distinct and the union of $C^{'}$ is Y?

Prove that the problem is in NP-complete.

1) Let G = (X,E) be a graph, S a subset of X and an interger k, we construct the following instance of COVERING BY TRIPLES by considering as a set Y = $S_{1}$ $\cup$ $S_{2}$ $\cup$ $S_{3}$, where the $S_{i}$ are some disjoint copies of S as family of triples C, the triples (x,y,z) of $S_{1}$ $\times$ $S_{2}$ $\times$ $S_{3}$ such that there exists in G a tree of size at most [3k/|Y|] containning the vertices of G which correspond to x, y and z.

2) Let be given a subet Y of size 3n and a family C of triples of Y. We construct an instance with X = {$x_{0}$} $\cup$ C $\cup$ Y as a set of vertices, E  = {$x_{0},c$ $\in C$} $\cup$ {(c,y)| c $\in$ C, y $\in$ Y} as a set of edges and S = {$x_{0}$} $\cup$ Y as the set of vertices to be connected and the maximal size of the network must be k = 4n.

Please help me why one of the two constructions that are proposed might be useful, while the other clearly cannot be of any help?, thanks a lot.

Comment: In this case, the word "hard" *does* add information :)

Comment: The Covering By Triples problem is also known as the Exact-Cover By 3-Set problem. If you are trying to prove that the problem is NP-Complete you need to reduce a known NP-Complete problem to it. If you are allowed to assume that 3-Dimensional Matching is NP-Complete, the reduction is shown here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025064/how-can-we-show-that-3-dimensional-matching-le-p-exact-cover?rq=1